# How to transfer variable from NSNumberFormatter to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, segue, number-formatting

I have a func with `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
@objc func doneClicked() {
                view.endEditing(true)


                let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                formatter.locale = Locale.current
                formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
                formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 6

                if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

                    year = number.doubleValue

                    mounthresult = year * 12

                    mounthLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: year).multiplying(by: 12))

                }
    }
```

I need to process a data transfer to `Label` in another `ViewController`.

Making a `prepare forSegue` `func`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yearmounth" {
        let mounthController = segue.destination as! MounthsViewController

        mounthController.mounth = mounthresult
}
```

In this case transferred var haven't formatting. And shows without localization.

```
mounthresult = formatter.number(from: mounthLabel.text!) as! Double
```

This case gives nothing too... It's transferred but shows without formatter.

Also i tried to insert `NumberFormatter` to another controller's `ViewDidLoad`. But in this case `NumberFormatter` isn't load in `ViewDidLoad`...

Anyone knows the ways of solution?

Comment: If you want to transfer the formatted number, why don't you transfer the formatted number (string) instead of the  umber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply pass formatted text:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yearmounth" {
        let mounthController = segue.destination as! MounthsViewController

        mounthController.mounth = mounthLabel.text
   }
```

Or store the number in a variable and pass it similar way.

Comment: I changed variable type to String and modified formatter method but now i got app crashed...

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'